# error launching SDK manager in Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

So far I have started working with Android Studio but the basic setup causing me a big pain. I have with me the latest JDK installed. All system variables are properly set. But the problem is when i try to launch SDK manager from Android Studio, it is giving me this error as you can see in this image

[image]

As far I think, the problem might be here

```
lib\\find_java.exe
```

i.e getting double slashes before find_java.exe. I don't know from where this double slashes coming out to be.

This is mine JAVA_HOME variable

```
F:\Java\Jdk1.8.0_25
```

and this one is PATH variable

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;F:\Java\Jdk1.8.0_25;F:\Java\Jdk1.8.0_25\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;F:\AndroidStudio\sdk\platform-tools
```

If anyone have ever suffered this before, please help me out. If you need any kind of screenshot or have any question, do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME defined? And Java SDK in at least version 7.

Comment: yes and i have already mentioned that in my question

Comment: I have it declared like this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71` without any `bin` or something.
"not recognized" sound like is some kind error while installing Android SDK. Maybe try re-install it.

Comment: see my edited question for PATH and JAVA_HOME variables

Comment: I've found this line in `find_java.bat` `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%~dps0\find_java.exe" -s') do set java_exe=%%a` Maybe edit path to specific location. I usually work with canary build of Android Studio (newest version without SDK) and SDK installed as standalone. Maybe try that.

Comment: I didn't get you, will you please elaborate??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65611/discussion-between-mateusz-jablonski-and-mukesh-rana).

Answer (score 0):

You must install Java 1.7, not 1.8. Check if your system is 32 or 64 bit and install appropriate Java JDK (not JRE). Before you install this you will not be able even to launch Android Studio.

A few days ago Java 1.8 64bit was causing that I was unable to open Android STudio so I installed 1.7 and all started to work fine.

After that, when you try to open Android Studio, it will offer you to set the environment. Choose "Custom" so you can manually set the path to Android SDK. After that Android Studio will update SDK if anything new is missing and you should be ready to go.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. Android Studio is working but `problem is when i try to launch SDK manager from Android Studio`

Comment: I don't think Java 1.7 can do the trick because earlier i was using that and it was still not working at that time so i updated to Java 1.8. But can you tell me how can i set environment variables in Android Studio??

Comment: @MukeshRana You set environment variables the same way as other in Windows. Go to Variable permissions and simply add path to Java JDK. So you are not setting it in AS, but in Windows system directly. I just did that in new Win8.1 installation a few days ago. Works flawlessly.

Comment: @MateuszJablonski Also in Project Structure, what does it say under SDK Location? Can you open that directory? Does it lead to your SDK folder?

Comment: don't you think that double slash is causing me the problem?? Do you have any idea from where that double slashes are coming out to be?

Comment: @MukeshRana I have never seen anything like that. Also double slash may mean that they are invoking the .exe. Just a guess. What Android Studio version do you use?